# MySQL Automatic Updater from CSV

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create an automatic score updater for a football database. My client will be emailing me CSV spreadsheets with the game date, home team, home score, visiting team, and visiting score in them. The problem is that I have a separate team table (team_id, team_name, etc.) and game table as outlined below:

team (team_id, team_name, etc.)

game(game_id, game_home_team, game_home_score, game_visitor_team, game_visitor_score, game_date, game_complete)

sample game data(1, 123, 0, 156, 0, 8-31-2012, No) -> I store the team's id instead of their name in the game table.

I need to write a script that will update the scores automatically. There will be about 327 scores per week.

The CSV will look like the following (with column headings):

game_date, home_team, home_score, visitor_team, visitor_score

(2012-8-31, Forest Hills, 44, Westmont Hilltop, 0) -> sample data

How would I first get the team id's, then match them home and visitor id's with their team names, then get the game id that corresponds to the matching team_id's, then update the scores for that game? That's a lot and I am kind of lost on the issue. Any help or even a better way to do this would be greatly appreciated. Below is what i have so far:

```
UPDATE game SET 
    game_home_score = ?, 
    game_visitor_score = ?, 
    game_complete = 'Yes' 
WHERE game_id = 
    SELECT game_id 
    FROM game 
    WHERE game_home_team IN (
        SELECT team_id 
        FROM team 
        WHERE team_name = ?
    ) AND game_visitor_team IN (
        SELECT team_id 
        FROM team 
        WHERE team_name = ?
    );
```

I know that query is wrong, but it's what I was thinking as far as the direction I need to go. My MySQL knowledge isn't quite vast enough (I don't think) to get this working.

Comment: Import the CSV data into a SQL table first. Then insert/update your structured tables from that raw data table. Keep unique indexes on the team's names in the team table and the combination (date,team_1,team_2). Then you can safely update and insert data in the same query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's put the data from the CSV file into a table called csv_data, then something like this should work:

```
update game g, csv_data c, team home_team, team visit_team
set g.game_home_score = c.home_score,
    g.game_visitor_score = c.visitor_score,
    g.game_complete = 'Yes'
where g.game_date = c.game_date
and home_team.team_name = c.home_team
and home_team.team_id = game.home_team
and visit_team.team_name = c.visit_team
and visit_team.team_id = game.visit_team
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will give this a shot and then report back here.